# Exposing Private Gke to API Gateway

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-api-gateway

---

> Having a GKE cluster with micro service . External IP of a service
> belongs to private subnet. I want to expose  a specific end points of the
> micro services to internet . Since there is no dns name  , I cannot
> able to integrate with API Gateway . Is there is a way ?

---

Comment: Why don't you expose the service with a LB type?

Comment: You can use one of these services to expose your GKE cluster

[https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/exposing-apps](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/exposing-apps)

Comment: Might I suggest a [load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https)? It's another way to expose said service, though it would be exposed to the internet as a whole, you might want to setup OAuth to expose it to only certain users on the internet.